# how to derive sales productivity

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables,

table 1 (Sales) has fields

```
saleDate,productID,sellPrice,costPrice, margin
```

table 2 (logSales) has fields

```
dateModified, sellPrice,costPrice and margin
```

when a sale is entered the data is posted to tables 1 & 2
If any of the values are modifed the new value is posted to the affected field in table 1 AND a new set of values (dateCreated, productID, sellPrice, costPrice and margin are posted to table 2.

what I am trying to achieve is to produce a dateRanged report which returns the actual productivity based on the margin per product where the original sale was created or modified within the specified date range, for example,

```
table 1
saleDate    productID sellPrice costPrice margin
2018-03-15     A1      1000.00    850.00  150.00
2018-05-02     A2      2000.00   1800.00  200.00

table 2
dateModified productID sellPrice costPrice margin  variance
2018-03-15     A1       1000.00    850.00  150.00    0.00 
2018-05-02     A2       2000.00   1800.00  200.00    0.00 
2018-05-05     A1       1000.00    910.00   90.00  -60.00
```

using the example if we ran a productivity report for March the result would be 150.00 however, running a report for May needs to show 200.00 for the May sale LESS 60.00 for the March sale modified in May so the actual productivity for May would be 140.00 with a variance of -60.00 this one has me completely stumped.

Answer (score 0):

To give you an accurate answer, I would need a little bit more explanations on the reasons why the prices change and the objectives of the report.

Nevertheless, based on your description of the problem, I would attack it on the following angles:

1- Add the sales from table 1 during the month AND add the total variance for the month from table 2:

```
SELECT SUM(data.performanceData) AS perfomance
FROM (
  SELECT SUM(margin) AS performanceData
  FROM table1
  WHERE saleDate BETWEEN '2018-05-01' AND '2018-05-30'
UNION ALL
  SELECT SUM(variance) AS performanceData
  FROM table2
  WHERE dateModified BETWEEN '2018-05-01' AND '2018-05-30'
) data
```

OR

2- Assume from table 2 that if variance = 0, then it is a new sale; otherwise, sum the variance:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(variance = 0, margin, variance)) AS performance
FROM table2
WHERE dateModified BETWEEN '2018-05-01' AND '2018-05-30'
```

Both queries will return performance of 150 for March and 140 for May.

To group by months:

```
SELECT data.monthID, SUM(data.performanceData) AS perfomance
FROM (
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(saleDate, "%Y-%m") AS monthID, SUM(margin) AS performanceData
  FROM table1
  GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(saleDate, "%Y-%m")
UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dateModified, "%Y-%m") AS monthID, SUM(variance) AS performanceData
  FROM table2
  GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(dateModified, "%Y-%m")
) data
GROUP BY monthID
```

OR

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dateModified, "%Y-%m") AS monthID, SUM(IF(variance = 0, margin, variance)) AS performance
FROM table2
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(dateModified, "%Y-%m")
```

Comment: the purpose of the report is to reflect net margin for the sale of any product where the sale is created OR altered in the date range

using travel as an example a product may have been sold in one month and the agency does not pay for it till say the next month, the actual Net/costPrice at time of settlement may have varied due to currency fluctuations therfore the margin will and is affected, the same applies IF the consultant varies the sell price prior to final payment

Comment: Then I believe the proposed queries should work. I was thinking if the price change several times during the same month; if the variance is calculated on the most recent price at time of the change, then adding the variances would be correct. If it is calculated on the original sale price, then only the most recent variance should be taken into consideration and the queries shall be update to group on products and select the latest. What do you think ?

Comment: Also, to produce for example a yearly report, you can remove the conditions and group at the end of the query: GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(dateModified, "%Y-%m"). See updated answer